# SQL Server Profiler

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-profiler

I have some stored procedure which doesn't work so fast as I expected.

```
declare @account_id integer = null
declare @house_id integer = 8
exec bills_supp_main '01.10.2013', '01.11.2013', @account_id, @house_id
```

In fact this procedure is "wrapper" for another procedures stack.
I have been trying to use SQL Server Profiler in order to get the list of all "wrapped" procedures and those duration.
But in result I got only duration of execution of "wrapper" procedure

(Unfortunately I couldn't post example image this)

How could I "ask" profiler to show me all calls of this procedure?
I want to find the critical one.

Tnanks.

Comment: Could you show us the outputs?

Comment: I think this question really needs a different title!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the event **Stored Procedures->SP:Completed** to the profiler trace. This will list the details of all executed stored procedures, both the "wrapper procedure" and any nested procedures, including `bills_supp_main`.